# How to use \newunicodechar for a character combined with a diacritical mark?

Tags: unicode, newunicodechar

I replace some commands with unicode characters to make my code more readable. Using `\newunicodechar`, it works fine with single unicode characters but fails with character combined with diacritics. This is a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{⏞}{\begin{Bmatrix}}
\newunicodechar{⏟}{\end{Bmatrix}}
%\newunicodechar{{ᷟ}{\begin{Bmatrix}}  % NOT WORKING
%\newunicodechar{}ᷟ}{\end{Bmatrix}}  % NOT WORKING


\begin{document}
   $⏞x\\y⏟$

  % ${ᷟx\\y}ᷟ$ % NOT WORKING
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Single unicode characters can also be used without `newunicodechar` with the following definition.

```
\makeatletter \@namedef{u8:\detokenize{⏞}}{\begin{Bmatrix}} \makeatother
\makeatletter \@namedef{u8:\detokenize{⏟}}{\end{Bmatrix}} \makeatother
```

Comment: Only one character is possible, directly. Can you tell what characters you have in mind?

Comment: I wouldn't call such command "more readable". If you are the only one to work on the file, it is your decision. But if the file should be handled also by others (e.g. a publisher or for latex support here on tex.sx) you are making life more difficult for them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you are right. I make it readable for myself, I have lots of matrices inside Tikz pictures.

Comment: @egreg I want to use e.g. }ᷟ (right brace with U+1DDF)

Comment: You can't redefine `{` and `}` to begin with. This would block you from typing arguments to commands.